# I need to clarify an answer from another post about an Audit

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I got this answer to my previous question ["Data stolen? What does this suspicious audit data mean?"](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162502/data-stolen-what-does-this-suspicious-audit-data-mean):

> BITS along with the TCP/IP network adapter detection and network data management protocol seem to indicate a transfer of files, wirelessly or through a new volume created by windows management instrumentation device it was one of the applications and it created a new volume with unknown hard drive usage.

What did that mean? I don't know why it was deleted and all other answers and comments except for one.

Comment: it was deleted because it didn't answer the question

Comment: It answers that data was stolen unless wrong in their analysis of the data?

Comment: they offered no explanation as to why they came up with that conclusion but instead asked 'others' to provide it